# transfer value from master page to another master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

i want to know if it is possible to transfer a value from a master page to anotehr master page? i want to transfer my "Name" value to the next masterpage. images shown below

the name "Jedi Ablaza" will be transffered into the next master page
[image: image 1]

and my code for my first master page

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a runat="server" href="~/" style="color: white">Home</a></li>

        <li id="forHR" runat="server" class="dropdown">
            <a id="hr" class="dropdown-toggle" runat="server" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="color: white">HR</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="HR/CoreValues.aspx">Core Values</a></li>
                <li><a href="HR/RaterEmpRelation.aspx">Rater & Employee Relation</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a id="toMosef" runat="server" href="MOSEF/WebForm1.aspx" style="color: white">MOSEF</a>
        </li>
```

to the highlighted portion of the new masterpage. 
[image: image 2]

how can I do that? thanks!

Comment: To achieve this,You can use session variables in your application

Comment: Refer this link and implement. [Link](http://odetocode.com/articles/450.aspx)

Comment: What about setting a public property from master page 1 and getting its value from master page 2 ?

Comment: What do you mean by "to another master page"? Typically a page only has one master page. Do you mean when the user clicks a link, etc? This question is very confusing

Comment: I think you can use session variable ...

Answer (score 1):

Use Sessions.

Assign to the session:

```
Session["username"] = txtusername.text;
```

retrieve from the session:

```
string username = Session["username"].toString();
```